# Is there any tool that let you batch export excel tabs to csv

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have Excel 2010.

Found this: [Batch XLS to CSV Converter](https://superuser.com/questions/340424/batch-xls-to-csv-converter)

But I actually need to export all excel worksheets as individual CSV files.
Not sure if it works that way.
Also if I were to use the above method, how do I actually use a VB script? (not familiar with programming)

Comment: using Windows 7

Comment: Just use COM from Python to spit them out.

Comment: To use Excel's VBA capabilities, press Alt + F11.  Then go to 'Insert' -> 'Module'.  Your code goes in the text window that opens.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a cleaned-up version of the script from the post to which you linked:

```
Option Explicit

Const xlXMLSpreadsheet = 46
Const xlCSV = 6

Dim xl, wb, ws

Dim args : Set args = WScript.Arguments

If args.Count <> 1 Then
  WScript.Echo "Syntax: cscript " & WScript.ScriptName & " filename"
  WScript.Quit(1)
End If

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(args(0))

xl.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
 ws.activate
 wb.SaveAs CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetBaseName(args(0)) _
   & "_" & Replace(ws.Name, " ", "_") & ".csv", xlCSV
Next
xl.DisplayAlerts = True

wb.Close False
xl.Quit
WScript.Quit
```

It should do what you want. You call it like this from a command prompt:

```
cscript SCRIPT.vbs INPUT.xls
```

It creates output files `INPUT_SHEETNAME.csv`.